# Sparse Matrix as a result of crossprod of sparse matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, term-document-matrix

I have been working around this problem for a while without finding a satisfactory solution.

I have data in a binary sparse matrix (TermDocumentMatrix) with dim (`[1] 340436 763717`). I here use an extract as proof of concept:

```
m = structure(list(i = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L), j = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), v = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), nrow = 5L, ncol = 3L, 
    dimnames = list(Terms = c("action", "activities", "advisory", "alike", "almanac"),
                    Docs = c("1000008721", "1000010083","1000013295"))), 
    class = c("TermDocumentMatrix", "simple_triplet_matrix"), weighting = c("binary", "bin"))

inspect(m)
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 5, documents: 3)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 8/7
Sparsity           : 47%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : binary (bin)
Sample             :
            Docs
Terms        1000008721 1000010083 1000013295
  action              1          0          0
  activities          1          1          0
  advisory            0          0          1
  alike               0          1          1
  almanac             1          0          1
```

I want to normalize to unit length every vectorized document, and then obtain a (sparse) matrix with the Docs on rows and Docs on cols and the dot product of the corresponding normalized vectors as values.

**Expected output:**

```
Sparse Matrix:
            Docs
Docs         1000008721 1000010083 1000013295 ... N
  1000008721  1.0000000  0.4082483  0.3333333     .
  1000010083  0.4082483  1.0000000  0.4082483     .  
  1000013295  0.3333333  0.4082483  1.0000000     .
    ...
   N               .          .          .

or also: data.table
 ID1              ID2          v
1000008721     1000008721      1
1000010083     1000008721     0.4082483
1000013295     1000008721     0.3333333
   ...             ...         ...
```

This would be easy to achieve with `crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(m)`  after applying the normalization with a function that divides every value for the norm. The euclidean norm in the with a binary vector reduces to `sqrt(col_sums(m))`.

Since I cannot by `as.matrix()` transformation ("Error: cannot allocate vector of size 968.6 Gb"), and I couldn't find any other way, I used data.table that may circumvent the need to apply a function over a sparse matrix:

```
# exploit the triples and manipulate through data.table
dt = as.data.table(list(i=m$i,j=m$j,v=m$v))

# obtain euclidean norm for every column 
dt[,e.norm:=list(as.numeric(sqrt(sum(v)))),by=j]

# divide the v for the corresponding group, subset and replace
dt = dt[,v.norm:=v/e.norm][,.(i,j,v.norm)][,v:=v.norm][,.(i,j,v)]

m$v <- dt$v
inspect(m)
            Docs
Terms        1000008721 1000010083 1000013295
  action      0.5773503  0.0000000  0.0000000
  activities  0.5773503  0.7071068  0.0000000
  advisory    0.0000000  0.0000000  0.5773503
  alike       0.0000000  0.7071068  0.5773503
  almanac     0.5773503  0.0000000  0.5773503
```

(What would the equivalent of this (maybe with slam) be?)

**QUESTION**: Given that `crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(tdm)` still returns a dense matrix (hence memory error) can you think about a similar data.table solution to return a sparse matrix with the cross product of two sparse matrices, or any alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 340436 x 763717 sparse matrix with 35879680 non-zero elements will result in a very large object (~30 GB). My machine isn't able to hold that object in memory with 16GB RAM. However, the cross product is straightforward to do piecemeal. The function `bigcrossprod` below performs the cross product in piecemeal, converts the results to `data.table` objects, and then `rbinds` the objects. The `crossprod` operation is broken into `nseg` separate operations.

```
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)

bigcrossprod <- function(m, nseg) {
  jmax <- ncol(m)
  # get the indices to split the columns of m into chunks that will have
  # approximately the same expense for crossprod
  sumj <- cumsum(as.numeric(jmax:1))
  dtj <- data.table(
    j = 1:jmax,
    int = sumj %/% (sumj[jmax]/nseg + 1)
  )[
    , .(idx1 = min(j), idx2 = max(j)), int
  ][, idx1:idx2]
  rbindlist(
    lapply(
      1:nseg,
      function(seg) {
        cat("\r", seg) # user feedback
        j1 <- dtj$idx1[seg]
        m2 <- as(triu(crossprod(m[, j1:dtj$idx2[seg],drop = FALSE],
                                m[, j1:jmax])), "dgTMatrix")
        data.table(
          i = attr(m2, "i") + j1,
          j = attr(m2, "j") + j1,
          v = attr(m2, "x")
        )
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Demonstrating with a somewhat smaller sparse matrix:

```
idx <- sample(34043*76371, 358796)
dt <- data.table(i = as.integer(((idx - 1) %% 34043L) + 1),
                 j = as.integer(((idx - 1) %/% 34043L) + 1),
                 key = "j")[, v := 1/sqrt(.N), j]
m <- sparseMatrix(dt$i, dt$j, x = dt$v)
# calculate crossprod on the full matrix and convert the result to triplet
# form in order to represent as a data.table
m2 <- as(crossprod(m), "dgTMatrix")
dt2 <- data.table(i = attr(m2, "i") + 1L,
                  j = attr(m2, "j") + 1L,
                  v = attr(m2, "x"))
# calculate crossprod in 10 chunks
dt3 <- bigcrossprod(m, 10)
#>  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# convert the result into a symmetric sparse matrix in triplet form (the same as m2)
m3 <- as(forceSymmetric(sparseMatrix(dt3$i, dt3$j, x = dt3$v)), "dgTMatrix")
# remove elements from the data.table objects that are redundant due to symmetry
dt2 <- unique(dt2[i > j, `:=`(i = j, j = i)])
dt3 <- setorder(dt3[i > j, `:=`(i = j, j = i)], i, j)
# check that the dgTMatrix and data.table objects are identical
identical(m2, m3)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(dt2, dt3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

In order to calculate the cross product of the 340436 x 763717 sparse matrix with 35879680 elements, instead of storing the list of `data.table` objects in a list to pass to `rbindlist`, save the individual data.table objects for later processing using the `fst` package. Instead of returning a single `data.table`, the following version of `bigcrossprod` returns a character vector of length `nseg` containing .fst file paths. Again, demonstrating with the smaller matrix:

```
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
library(fst)

bigcrossprod <- function(m, nseg, path) {
  jmax <- ncol(m)
  # get the indices to split the columns of m into chunks that will have
  # approximately the same expense for crossprod
  sumj <- cumsum(as.numeric(jmax:1))
  dtj <- data.table(
    j = 1:jmax,
    int = sumj %/% (sumj[jmax]/nseg + 1)
  )[
    , .(idx1 = min(j), idx2 = max(j)), int
  ][, idx1:idx2]
  vapply(
    1:nseg,
    function(seg) {
      cat("\r", seg) # user feedback
      j1 <- dtj$idx1[seg]
      m2 <- as(triu(crossprod(m[, j1:dtj$idx2[seg], drop = FALSE],
                              m[, j1:jmax])), "dgTMatrix")
      filepath <- file.path(path, paste0("dt", seg, ".fst"))
      write.fst(
        data.table(
          i = attr(m2, "i") + j1,
          j = attr(m2, "j") + j1,
          v = attr(m2, "x")),
        filepath
      )
      filepath
    },
    character(1)
  )
}

idx <- sample(34043*76371, 358796)
dt <- data.table(i = as.integer(((idx - 1) %% 34043L) + 1),
                 j = as.integer(((idx - 1) %/% 34043L) + 1),
                 key = "j")[, v := 1/sqrt(.N), j]
m <- sparseMatrix(dt$i, dt$j, x = dt$v)
# calculate crossprod on the full matrix and convert the result to triplet
# form in order to represent as a data.table
m2 <- as(crossprod(m), "dgTMatrix")
dt2 <- data.table(i = attr(m2, "i") + 1L,
                  j = attr(m2, "j") + 1L,
                  v = attr(m2, "x"))
# calculate crossprod in 10 chunks, read the resulting .fst files,
# and rbindlist into a single data.table
dt3 <- rbindlist(lapply(bigcrossprod(m, 10, "C:/temp"),
                        function(x) read.fst(x, as.data.table = TRUE)))
#> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# convert the result into a symmetric sparse matrix in triplet form (the same as m2)
m3 <- as(forceSymmetric(sparseMatrix(dt3$i, dt3$j, x = dt3$v)), "dgTMatrix")
# remove elements from the data.table objects that are redundant due to symmetry
dt2 <- unique(dt2[i > j, `:=`(i = j, j = i)])
dt3 <- setorder(dt3[i > j, `:=`(i = j, j = i)], i, j)
# check that the dgTMatrix and data.table objects are identical
identical(m2, m3)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(dt2, dt3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I was able process a 340436 x 763717 sparse matrix with 35879680 non-zero elements in about 15 minutes with 16GB of RAM.

**Explanation:**

A walkthrough of the logic in `bigcrossprod` using the OP's 5 x 3 example matrix:

```
idx <- c(1,2,5,7,9,13:15)
dt <- data.table(i = as.integer(((idx - 1) %% 5) + 1),
                 j = as.integer(((idx - 1) %/% 5) + 1),
                 key = "j")[, v := 1/sqrt(.N), j]
(m <- sparseMatrix(dt$i, dt$j, x = dt$v))
#> 5 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                                   
#> [1,] 0.5773503 .         .        
#> [2,] 0.5773503 0.7071068 .        
#> [3,] .         .         0.5773503
#> [4,] .         0.7071068 0.5773503
#> [5,] 0.5773503 .         0.5773503
nseg <- 2 # process the cross product of m in two chunks
jmax <- ncol(m)
sumj <- cumsum(as.numeric(jmax:1))
# In order to balance the processing between chunks, process column 1 first,
# then columns 2:3 next. Each crossprod call will result in 3 elements.
(dtj <- data.table(j = 1:jmax, int = sumj %/% (sumj[jmax]/nseg + 1))[, .(idx1 = min(j), idx2 = max(j)), int][, idx1:idx2])
#>    idx1 idx2
#> 1:    1    1
#> 2:    2    3
# process the first chunk
seg <- 1L
j1 <- dtj$idx1[seg]
# cross product of column 1 and the full matrix
(m2 <- as(crossprod(m[, j1:dtj$idx2[seg], drop = FALSE], m[, j1:jmax]), "dgTMatrix"))
#> 1 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#>                           
#> [1,] 1 0.4082483 0.3333333
# The indices of m2 are 0-based. Add j1 to the i,j indices of m2 when converting
# to a data.table.
(dt1 <- data.table(i = attr(m2, "i") + j1, j = attr(m2, "j") + j1, v = attr(m2, "x")))
#>    i j         v
#> 1: 1 1 1.0000000
#> 2: 1 2 0.4082483
#> 3: 1 3 0.3333333
# process the second chunk
seg <- 2L
j1 <- dtj$idx1[seg] # starts at column 2
# Cross product of columns 2:3 and columns 2:jmax (2:3). The end result
# will be a symmetric matrix, so we need only the upper triangular matrix.
(m2 <- as(triu(crossprod(m[, j1:dtj$idx2[seg], drop = FALSE], m[, j1:jmax])), "dgTMatrix"))
#> 2 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgTMatrix"
#>                 
#> [1,] 1 0.4082483
#> [2,] . 1.0000000
(dt2 <- data.table(i = attr(m2, "i") + j1, j = attr(m2, "j") + j1, v = attr(m2, "x")))
#>    i j         v
#> 1: 2 2 1.0000000
#> 2: 2 3 0.4082483
#> 3: 3 3 1.0000000
# the final matrix (in data.table form) is the two data.tables row-bound
# together (in bigcrossprod, the lapply returns a list of data.table objects for
# rbindlist)
(dt3 <- rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2)))
#>    i j         v
#> 1: 1 1 1.0000000
#> 2: 1 2 0.4082483
#> 3: 1 3 0.3333333
#> 4: 2 2 1.0000000
#> 5: 2 3 0.4082483
#> 6: 3 3 1.0000000
# dt3 can be converted to a symmetric sparse matrix
(m3 <- forceSymmetric(sparseMatrix(dt3$i, dt3$j, x = dt3$v)))
#> 3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#>                                   
#> [1,] 1.0000000 0.4082483 0.3333333
#> [2,] 0.4082483 1.0000000 0.4082483
#> [3,] 0.3333333 0.4082483 1.0000000
```

And, finally, a parallel version of `bigcrossprod` (for Linux):

```
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
library(parallel)
library(fst)

bigcrossprod <- function(m, nseg, path, nthreads = nseg) {
  jmax <- ncol(m)
  # get the indices to split the columns of m into chunks that will have
  # approximately the same expense for crossprod
  sumj <- cumsum(as.numeric(jmax:1))
  dtj <- data.table(
    j = 1:jmax,
    int = sumj %/% (sumj[jmax]/nseg + 1)
  )[
    , .(idx1 = min(j), idx2 = max(j)), int
  ][, idx1:idx2]
  cl <- makeCluster(nthreads, type = "FORK", outfile = "")
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
  unlist(
    parLapply(
      cl,
      1:nseg,
      function(seg) {
        j1 <- dtj$idx1[seg]
        m2 <- as(triu(crossprod(m[, j1:dtj$idx2[seg],drop = FALSE],
                                m[, j1:jmax])), "dgTMatrix")
        filepath <- file.path(path, paste0("dt", seg, ".fst"))
        write.fst(
          data.table(
            i = attr(m2, "i") + j1,
            j = attr(m2, "j") + j1,
            v = attr(m2, "x")),
          filepath
        )
        filepath
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you... with my data I am having "Error in .local(x, y = y, ...) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_sparse.c, line 89" I can try to reduce the size of the original matrix a little, by filtering out not relevant terms and docs

Comment: Additionally, how could I bring along the colnames of orig m to colnames and rownames of final m? (I want to get a dt with ID1 ID2 and v that becomes the dt with weights for a network) 
`colnames(m) <- names(tdm)` ?

Comment: Which command results in the error?

Comment: Matrix::crossprod(Matrix::sparseMatrix(dt$i, dt$j, x = dt$v))

Comment: What do you have for `dim(dt)`?

Comment: Dim returns 35879680 3

Comment: That will result in a very large object. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer to work with objects larger than can fit in memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have 32gb + swap set at 900gb just for this task, still had the error problem too large. On the other hand, I could process my matrix with your solution. I am still trying to understand the function though (I have taken it as a black box and applied for now) could you write some comments about its logic? how could I bring along the original doc names to the new dt with this function?

Comment: The `i` and `j` in the resulting `data.table`(s) correspond with the original matrix. Say `nms` is a character vector of the column names, the row names in a resulting `data.table` would be `nms[dt$i]`, and the column names would be `nms[dt$j]`.

Comment: I added a walkthrough of the logic at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to use `triu` to simplify `bigcrossprod` a bit.

Comment: The more I think about it the more I like this function, I'll try to expand it to `future_lapply` for which I think it is fit..

Comment: Yes. Or the `lapply` could easily be changed to a `parLapply`. I didn't do parallel because I was already close to using all my 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Just one thing you may want to change: `> m <- sparseMatrix(dt$i, dt$j, x = dt$v)
> dim(m)
[1] 34043 76371 ` You processed a 34043x76371 with 358796 non-zero entries and not the 340430x763717 with 35879680 but I can confirm that by using my swap a bit the function can achieve that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244280/discussion-between-karrowsbest-and-jblood94).